# How do I make the cursor blink?

Tags: vimrc, cursor, linux-ubuntu

`set guicursor=n:blinkwait5-blinkon5-blinkoff5` has no effect.

Why is that?

[mp4](https://i.gyazo.com/53fce613901e0e0d50089facd242321b.mp4)

Comment: If this is Vim and not GVim, then you might need to change your terminal settings to change the cursor blink... Not sure if you'd be able to tweak that for Vim only and not other programs running on the terminal...

Answer (score 3):

*:set guicursor&* should restore cursor defaults in GVim.

Edit:
To change the blink rate try using guicursor=a instead of guicursor=n like this :

```
:set guicursor=a:blinkwait5-blinkon5-blinkoff5
```

This will ONLY work in GVim, not Vim.

Comment: But how do I set a custom blinkwait, blinkon, and blinkoff time for the guicursor`?

Comment: It still doesn't work: [mp4](https://i.gyazo.com/9fe76ec552aec5f889f08dd45a5340a2.mp4). It is supposed to blink faster than what it does in the video ... right?

Comment: @SebastianNielsen Right. On my system it blinks incredibly fast but it only works on GVim not Vim.

Comment: oh, I see, any idea on how to apply it on vim?

Comment: @SebastianNielsen I don't think that you can apply it to Vim. The GUI in guicursor stands for Graphical User Interface... That's GVim... Graphical Vim.

Comment: @bashBedlam Please [edit] your answer to explain that this only works on GVim and not Vim, that's probably relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

I use Vim in the terminal, and have it set so that I have a block cursor in
normal mode, and a thin blinking bar cursor when in insert mode:

```
augroup cursor_behaviour
    autocmd!

    " reset cursor on start:
    autocmd VimEnter * silent !echo -ne "\e[2 q"
    " cursor blinking bar on insert mode
    let &t_SI = "\e[5 q"
    " cursor steady block on command mode
    let &t_EI = "\e[2 q"

    " highlight current line when in insert mode
    autocmd InsertEnter * set cursorline
    " turn off current line highlighting when leaving insert mode
    autocmd InsertLeave * set nocursorline

augroup END
```

Maybe you can adapt this function to your needs.

Comment: Doesn't this code cause the original cursor shape not to be restored upon exiting `vim`?